# ACT ID gives 403 from Paypal IPN

Tags: ee2, add-on-development, paypal

I created a function in ee module to handle Paypal IPN as follows:

```
function ipn_paypal(){
    include_once("libraries/Paypal_lib.php");

    $objPaypal = new Paypal_Lib();
    $objPaypal->process_order();        
}
```

where process_order function is written in a separate file inside libraries as "Paypal_lib.php". Inside this library file the function is:

```
function process_order() {
    if ($this->validate_ipn()) {

    }
}
```

But Paypal gets a 403 error when the following ACT is called:

```
http://domaim.com/?ACT=54
```

I even tried creating an ee template and calling the IPN function inside template,  but still Paypal sees a 403 error.

Strange thing is that when I call the same ACT URL from browser it runs fine. Seems when Paypal sends a POST to the ACT URL, some issue happens.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried POSTing to the URL? Or just GET from the browser? You might try an app like Rested, which allows you to send a post request, so you can simulate the IPN. Also, I know PayPal offers an IPN simulator in their developers site. Have you tried that?